# Filtering a list in c#

Tags: c#

So i have two lists .One is an `Attorney` object list and the other is a list with `GUID` .I am first just filling the `GUID` list with values and then looping through it and then matching it to the `ID` field of `Attorney` object to get the Attorney's with the given `ID` .

Is there a nicer way than my try to achieve this.

```
List<Attorney> Attorneys = msg.CaseDocument.Attorneys;
List<Attorney> CaseDefendantAtt = new List<Attorney>();
List<Guid> AttorneyID = new List<Guid>();

foreach (var s in msg.CaseDocument.Defendants)
{
    AttorneyID.AddRange(s.Attorneys);               

}
foreach (var p in AttorneyID)
{
    var z = Attorneys.FindAll(o => o.AttorneyId == p);
    if (z != null)
    {
        CaseDefendantAtt.AddRange(z);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about...

```
var caseDefendantAtt = msg.CaseDocument.Attorneys.Where(o =>
        msg.CaseDocument.Defendants.SelectMany(d => d.Attorneys).Contains(o.AttorneyId));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var allAttorneyIds = msg.CaseDocument.Defendants.SelectMany(x=> x.Attroneys);
var caseDefendantsAtt = msg.CaseDocument.Attorneys.Where(x=> allAttorneyIds.Contains(x.AttorneyId)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could store your Attorneys in a Dictionary of [Guid, Attorney], then looking for each Guid in Dictionary.

```
Dictionary<Guid, Attorney> Attorneys = CreateDictionaryFrom(msg.CaseDocument.Attorneys);
List<Attorney> CaseDefendantAtt = new List<Attorney>();
List<Guid> AttorneyID = new List<Guid>();

foreach (var s in msg.CaseDocument.Defendants)
{
     AttorneyID.AddRange(s.Attorneys);               
}

foreach (var p in AttorneyID)
{
     var z = Attorneys[p];
     if (z != null)
     {
         CaseDefendantAtt.Add(z);
     }
 }
```

It will increase the performance with the x1000 factor. But you should notice that we assume there is only one attorney per Guid. 
Without using a dictionary, we could improve your search in list seeking for FirstOrDefault instead of FindAll